# Increase number of shown posts by a "Site Feed" (Newsfeed) web part

Tags: web-part, newsfeed, sitefeed

I need to increase the number of posts shown by a "Site Feed" web part. The best would be to see all posts.

Does anyone know the functionality of the "show more posts" button? I can´t find the the correct javascript/JSOM library for that.

Thanks and Greetz!

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box setting to set the post count but you achieve using JavaScript which I found on the below POST.

```
$('.ms-microfeed-thread:gt(2)').hide(); //hides all posts after the three latests
$('#ms-MoreThreadsButtonLabel').click(function (){$('.ms-microfeed-thread').show();}); // sets a click function on the morethreads button to show them again
```

[Limit the amount of posts for Newsfeed (Site)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/103438/limit-the-amount-of-posts-for-newsfeed-site)

Comment: OP wants to INCREASE the number of displayed posts, not LIMIT it.

Comment: Unfortunately Jussi Palo is right.